# Translating Italian prepositions in poetry

Tags: translation, prepositions

In terms of vocabulary, may the word 'per', as in canto 1 of the Inferno, be translated into the English phrase 'by means of'?

Here's the excerpt in question:

> Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
>   mi ritrovai per una selva oscura
>   ché la diritta via era smarrita.

Comment: Which instance of 'per' do you mean? I count 16 different occurrences in Inferno 1.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I agree with @gbutters: could you please be more explicit and quote the text you are referring to?

Comment: If you're referring to “Per me si va nella città dolente”, then it's *through* (but it's not in Canto 1).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am  interested in 'per' in line  2 of canto 1 Inferno,

Comment: @rjlamberti: This question, as it is phrased, is borderline off-topic here. As you can see in the answers and questions, most of us don't master English so as to tell you how to translate something *into* English, nor this is the topic of this site. At most we can try to explain – as we are trying to do – what that *per* was supposed to mean, and then you can see yourself how to translate it (if English is your first language) or ask someone else, for instance on ELU.

Comment: Many (Italian) students are confused by this *che*... in Italian poetry: *ché* is the contraction for *perché*. A rough translation of the verse is (using Longfellow's one as a model) "I found myself within a forest dark **because** the straight-forward pathway had been lost": it's just cause and effect! Often texts don't use the accent, so isn't easy to recognize it! If you are reading poetry and can't understand what *che* stands for, try to use *perché* as "why" or "because". If it doesn't make sense, use regular *che* instead. p.s. Sorry for my English (plus: I'm totally new on this page!)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Loredana! What you are saying is interesting, but I'm not sure you are really answering to the question. Another thing: where you are saying "what *can* stands for", I think it should be "what *che* stands for", isn't it?

Comment: Hello @Charo! Ops, what I've read then? I was sure you were asking for _che_! Like @kos said before, I'd totally go for _within_!Sorry for my embarrassing mistake, ah ah!

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Midway upon the journey of our life
>   I found myself within a forest dark,
>   For the straight-forward pathway had been lost.

Henry Wadsworth Longfellow, himself a poet, [translated it as "within"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Divine_Comedy/Inferno/Canto_I). My guess is that he did not choose something like *through*, as others have suggested, because *through* indicate that the action is over or the subject knows where is going. Dante is travelling inside the forest, but he is not passing through as if he knows where is going. He is wandering inside of it, he doesn't know even how has arrived there ("I found myself"); he is lost.

*Within* represent the idea that he is moving inside the forest while not really moving forward to his destination. Indeed Dante doesn't even know where he should go.

Answer (score 4):

> Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
>   mi ritrovai per una selva oscura
>   ché la diritta via era smarrita.

In this case *per* means something like *through*: the poet is in a dark forest and wandering through it.

Comment: Personally I would have said more "in" than "through", although undoubtfully eventually Dante ends up wandering "through" the dark forest and, as we know, gets "through" it.

Comment: I agree with “through” (the sense being that Dante finds himself travelling and not standing in the forest) and, as soon as possible, will support this quoting some comment of the Commedia.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, I think the closest preposition in English would be neither "through" nor "in", but rather "by".

Comment: ("by" to be read as "by" in "I (Dante) "found myself" (forgive the poor translation but I really don't know how to express this better) by a dark forest", although in this specific case I think "in" would fit better: "I "found myself" in a dark forest", while I don't think "through" would fit well: "I "found myself" through a dark forest"; I think the truth is there's no specific preposition in English to convey the exact same meaning, and that the meaning shall be found in something in between "in" and "by".)

Comment: Right, perhaps “through” is not the right way of translating it. On the other hand, this is not the right site to give explanation about English words. The sense is that “*per*” is more dynamic than “*in*”, denoting that Dante is not still in some spot of a dark wood, but he realises he is *moving* in/through/by/within indefinite places of the wood. The best way of rendering this into English is best left with English-speaking people, perhaps in EL&U.SE.

Comment: @DaG Indeed, in fact I upvoted egreg's answer already, my point about using an alleged (alleged because English is not my mother tongue) "closer" preposition was made for the purpose of possibly suggesting a way to convey the meaning as better as possible (despite the fact that the suggestion itself might be wrong; just "my 2 cents"), since the abovementioned usage of "per" is quite atypical; indeed not to pickily remark the grammar or argue about the usage of prepositions in English, which would be definetly out of the scope of the answer and, mostly, I would never entitle myself to do.

Comment: @DaG I too think that the correct translation is not *through*: it's *moto in luogo circoscritto*, which has no direct correspondent in English, as far as I know. So some periphrasis is necessary, or just another choice as Longfellow did.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents on this one.

The verb "ritrovare", in its reflexive form "ritrovarsi", means, roughly, per se in this context, "to find oneself in some place without having explicitly wanted such thing to happen"; quoting [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ritrovare/):

> 4. [...] b. [...] accorgersi di essere capitati in qualche posto, senza averlo esplicitamente voluto o senza aspettarselo: Mi ritrovai per una selva oscura (Dante) [...]

Apologize in advance for the bolded text, which always makes me picture OPs like they are screaming, but I believe that here resides the key for the correct interpretation of "per" in this context, and I think that to remark it it's necessary: **mind that "ritrovarsi", whilst it indeed implies the subject having been in movement until the action of "ritrovarsi" itself takes place, doesn't imply, anywhere, the subject being still in movement whatsoever, because "ritrovarsi"'s meaning itself (as mentioned by Treccani) means else, and addresses the fact that the subject *realized and became conscious* of the fact that they are in some place they didn't explicitly wanted to be in**, and hence really says nothing about the subject being or not being in movement; so thinking of the subject as being still in movement at the time of this happening would be rather an assumption.

Now, on the following "per": [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/per/) mentions **13** different acceptations of "per" (excluding variations); I went through all of them, and, for the above, I believe that this is the acceptation that best describes the meaning of "per" in this context (I italicized the relevant part):

> 1. [...] b. Per indicare il luogo entro il quale avviene un movimento (compl. di moto entro luogo), senza riferimento alla direzione di tale moto: passeggiare, girare per la città; andare, viaggiare, cercare per monti e per valli. *Acquista in simili casi funzioni analoghe a quelle della prep. in, e ciò avviene anche con verbi di quiete per indicare una distribuzione entro una certa area*: le quali [macchie] nelle braccia e per le cosce ... apparivano a molti (Boccaccio); avere dolori per le ossa, per tutto il corpo.

Roughly translated: "[...] It acquires, in similiar cases, functions comparable to those of the preposition "in", and this happens also with "verbi di quiete<sup>1</sup>" to indicate a distribution within a certain area [...]".

So, in my opinion, being "ritrovarsi" **not** a "verbo di movimento<sup>1</sup>" **but rather** a "verbo di quiete<sup>1</sup>", and being Dante not in a specific point of the dark forest but rather vaguely somewhere inside it, *this is the acceptation that best describes the meaning of "per" in this context*; what comes after in the plot, such as Dante being wandering through the dark forest, should be excluded from the interpretation, as it just comes after.

Hence, for the above, coming to the translation, I'd either second "within", which I think has the privilege over "in" to also express that the subject is inside a certain boundary, or, more simply, just "in".

<sub>1: "Verbi di movimento", as opposed to "verbi di quiete", quoting [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-di-movimento_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/), "express in various ways a change of position of an entity from a point to another in the space or, figuratively, in the time.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The meaning that is conveyed here is "wading through": "I found myself wading through a dark forest". That action in itself does not imply being lost, however "Mi ritrovai..." ("I found myself...") makes it clear that entering the forest wasn't intentional, and "ché la diritta via era smarrita" makes the fact of having lost the way quite explicit.